# Rendering HTML from string in 500x500 size div

Tags: html, angularjs, rendering

I've have some html contents in angularjs array:

```
var HTMLs = [];
```

`HTMLs` is a string array with following HTML content in it.

```
<p><img src="http: //www.pw.com/Emblems/598e97fa05454766902650b4c01d7645.jpg" style="width: 25%;" /><p>
```

---

```
<p><span style="font-weight: bold;">This is a sample heading.</span></p><p><span style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;">Some content without any image.</span></p>
```

I want to have display preview image of these HTML texts after rendering in a div of size 500x500 for each html content from the array.

I don't want any scroll bars in the `div` for `HTML` rendered. If the `HTML` text is too long then small portion rendering would work for me.

Comment: Can you post the c# code you currently have that's attempting to do this.

Comment: I would have awarded you the `golden` badge for your `very helpful` and `supportive` comment but I don't have privilages :)

Answer (score 2):

You can take out the required html part from the  hole string using getElementById method, and assign it to the div.

```
var xSection = document.getElementById("sectionid");
document.getElementById("divid").innerHTML = xSection.innerHTML;
```

OR you can use **ng-bind-html** in the HTML:

```
    <div ng-bind-html="anyVariable"></div>
```

At this point you would get a **attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context** error so you need to use **$sce** to resolve that.

```
    $sce.trustAsHtml()
```

in the controller to convert the html string.

```
    $scope.anyVariable = $sce.trustAsHtml(someHtmlVar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
Create a function:

$scope.renderHtml = function(html_code)
{
   return $sce.trustAsHtml(html_code);
};
```

Your Controller:

```
angular.module('HtmlRenderModule').controller('HtmlRenderController', ['$scope', '$http', '$sce',
function ($scope, $http, $sce) {
    $scope.renderHtml = function (htmlCode) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlCode);
    };

    $scope.body = Htmls[0]; 
}
```

In your HTML, bind the value like this way:

```html
 <div ng-controller="MyController">
        <div  ng-bind-html="renderHtml(body)"></div>
    </div>
```

If you want that this should render only in 500*500 div and any other design changes you want to apply, use your own custom CSS for this. Obviously you should iterate through all html strings in your input array. I have just used one element here for example.